# How to render any event function on page load in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In select tag, there is a function `loadTags()`, which is called on `onclick` event. I am using mvc4      and want to call it with `_layout.cshtml` i.e shared view:

```
<div class="left-menu">
    <select id="tid" name="tags" onclick="loadTags()" >
        <option value="tags">--Tags--</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

How should I call this function on page load. Here is `loadTags()` function

```
function loadTags() {
    $("#tid option").remove();
    var d = $("#tid").val();
    var str = "--Tags--";
    $.post("/Status/allTags", function (data) {
        $("#tid").append('<option>' + str + '</option>');
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $("#tid").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + item + '</option>');
        });
    }, "json");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use jQuery?

```
$(function() {
    loadTags();
});
```

Make sure jQuery is loaded before you call this line of code.

I don't think loading the tags when the user clicks the element is a good approach. For instance, when the user uses the tab key to navigate to this element, the tags will not load.

Also, if you are loading the tags on page load, does it still make sense to load them via AJAX? Can't you include them in the page itself?

Comment: As a side not, could be just write: `$(loadTags);`

Answer (score 2):

put your code in [document.ready](http://jqapi.com/#p=ready) function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadTags();
});
```

or shorter:

```
$(function () {
    loadTags();
});
```

or even shorter:

```
$(loadTags);
```

**[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fk4asny/)**

`.ready()`:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.

Comment: Or even shorter `$(loadTags);`